# Dotnetty WriteAsync not working but WriteAndFlushAsync does

Tags: c#, asynchronous, networking, dotnetty

I'm working on a server and I'm making use of DotNetty. What the server does is receive a message, check it's header and then invoking the right message event. This works all but one thing.

Let's say I have a message event called `LoginMessageEvent`. In here you want to send multiple responses (= composer), like the login result and client details. So my idea was having a QueueComposer function like this:

```
public Task QueueComposer(Composer composer)
{
    return _channel.WriteAsync(composer);
}
```

And having a Flush function like this:

```
public void Flush()
{
    _channel.Flush();
}
```

(_channel = IChannel)

So in my message event, the part of sending stuff would like:

```
public async Task Handle(Session session, Event message)
{
    Player player = await _playerController.Login(username, password);

    if (player != null)
    {
        await session.QueueComposer(LoginResult.Compose(true));
        await session.QueueComposer(ClientDetails.Compose(session));
        session.Flush();
    }
    else
    {
        await session.Disconnect();
    }
}
```

However, this won't do anything. As some events only send one response, I also have a function where it will call `WriteAndFlushAsync`, like this:

```
public async Task SendComposer(Composer composer)
{
    await _channel.WriteAndFlushAsync(composer);
}
```

If I'll change the code in the if statement in this:

```
await session.SendComposer(LoginResult.Compose(true));
await session.SendComposer(ClientDetails.Compose(session));
```

My mind though thinks this is not ideal, so I was wondering why the separate `QueueComposer` and `Flush` doesn't work.